# npm not work in windows 7

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-start

I install the nodejs its work wihtout any problem but when I try to install some packge with the npm.
The npm not work and give me this problem:

```
error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
```

This the varaible system path:

[image]

[image]

The floder `C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm` is empty.

I dont now what is the problem why not work?

Comment: Go to the terminal command and try to run your folder path and then write these code npm install npm -g or npm install npm

Comment: the same message error

Answer (score 0):

npm usually comes shipped with Node. Setup issues are very common while working with Node. I think it will be faster for You to do a clean reinstall than try to fix Your issue.

What I found working the best for me is using nvm. It's a command line tool which lets You install any version of Node and switch to any other version at any time.

You are on Windows 7, so what You are interested in is **nvm-setup.zip** from this source:
https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases

Run the setup and if it asks You about controlling versions press yes.

Now, run Your cmd.

```
Administrator@MECH-PC D:\a
$ nvm list

  * 6.8.1 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
    5.0.0
    4.0.0
    0.10.38

Administrator@MECH-PC D:\a
$ node -v
v6.8.1

Administrator@MECH-PC D:\a
$ npm -v
3.10.8

Administrator@MECH-PC D:\a
$ nvm install 5
5.0.0
Downloading node.js version 5.0.0 (64-bit)... Complete
Creating C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\nvm\temp

Downloading npm version 3.3.6... Complete
Installing npm v3.3.6...

Installation complete. If you want to use this version, type

nvm use 5.0.0

Administrator@MECH-PC D:\a
$ nvm use 5
5.0.0
Now using node v5.0.0 (64-bit)

Administrator@MECH-PC D:\a
$ nvm list

    6.8.1
  * 5.0.0 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
    4.0.0
    0.10.38

Administrator@MECH-PC D:\a
$ node -v
v5.0.0

Administrator@MECH-PC D:\a
$ npm -v
3.3.6
```

**Note**

On Windows `nvm use` will persist selected version. In unix You need `nvm alias default [VERSION]` e.g. `nvm alias default 6.8.1`

**Additional reading for unix guys:**

http://www.nearform.com/nodecrunch/nodejs-sudo-free/

Answer (score 0):

@Kamil Mech
I install tje nvm dna work but howa can I  in integrate with nodejs ???

[image]

oooh I dont now where is the porblem but the npm now work